# Neo4J Params on Javascript

Tags: javascript, neo4j, parameters

I´m sure that one of you can help me with this issue.
I´m trying to create a node property with "params", but I must be missing something because nothing happens. I neither received a console.log error, nor the param is working properly.
I could console.log the requested variables, so that the request of the app is working, too.

Thank you for your help.

```js
app.post("/person/originalname/add", function (req, res) {
    var originalname = req.body.originalname;
    var id = req.body.id;

    session
        .run("MATCH (n) where id(n) = $idParam SET n.original_name = $originalParam RETURN n", {
            originalParam: originalname,
            idParam: id
        }
        )
        .then(function (result) {
            res.redirect('/');

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

});
```

Comment: Does `MATCH (n) where id(n) = $idParam RETURN n` return something in Neo4j browser (in the browser, you can use the `:params` syntax to define parameters or replace `$idParam` with the corresponding value instead)?

Comment: @fbiville. Thank you for your comments. I changed it to $props and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @fbiville helped me as a hint to get to an answer. I changed the param of the property to props and now it works.
Thank you

```
app.post("/person/originalname/add", function(req, res) {
  var originalname = req.body.originalname;
  var id = req.body.id;

  session
    .run(
      "MATCH (n) where id(n) = $idParam SET n = $props",
      {
        props: {
          "original_name": originalname
        },
        idParam: id
      })

    .then(function(result) {
      res.redirect('/');

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    });

});
```